# Convert a matrix into a dataframe

Tags: r

This a generic question, let' say I have:

```
matrix=replicate(5, rnorm(10))
```

I want a data.frame with 3 columns: row number, column number, matrix value.

Comment: that's not what I have in mind, I want a data.frame with 3 columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `melt` inside `library(reshape)`

```
melt(matrix)
```

edit: use `reshape2` instead.

Comment: Good point, it would be better to use `reshape2.` `reshape::melt()` and `reshape2::melt()` seem to be functionally identical.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `row`, `col`, and `c` functions for an R Base solution and  try something like this

```
df <- data.frame(row=c(row(matrix)), col=c(col(matrix)), value=c(matrix))
```

Comment: Nice. I'll mention [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176781/r-matrix-to-rownames-colnames-values/11176964) which has examples for producing a data.frame with rownames/colnames/value.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
data.frame(cbind(arrayInd(seq_along(matrix), dim(matrix), useNames = T), 
                 value = c(matrix)))
```

Or:

```
tmp = as.data.frame.table(matrix)
tmp[-length(tmp)] = sapply(tmp[-length(tmp)], as.integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way is just to use "as.data.frame"

```
as.data.frame(matrix)
```

see more conversion at [https://www.statmethods.net/management/typeconversion.html]