# Convert matrix to SPSS-like format in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, spss

So I am trying to convert a set of data that is in matrix format, like this

```
  V1  V2  V3  V4
1 12  32  12  54
2 43  34  23  24
3 43  23  65  54
```

etc. where 1-3 are seqID and V1-4 are ID

I would like to have it in a format that's easier for SPSS to understand, like this:

```
ID  seqID  Value
1      1   12
2      1   32
3      1   12
4      1   54
1      2   43
```

etc.

What would be the best way to do this in R? It should be some simple text manipulation, and I tried making a loop to solve it (eg by extracting columns, then binding the values again) but somehow loop syntax still escapes me! Help appreciated!

Comment: See @EDi s answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176781/r-matrix-to-rownames-colnames-values

Comment: What you are after is known as "long" format. What you have is "wide" format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to SO. You can do that using the melt function from `reshape2` package. Suppose `dt` is your matrix.

```
dt=as.data.frame(dt)
dt$seqID = 1:nrow(dt)
melt(dt, id = "seqID")
```

Comment: Fantastic! Glad I finally made an account, this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Data generation:

```
m <- matrix(c(12, 43, 43, 32, 34, 23, 12, 23, 65, 54, 24, 54), nrow = 3, 
            dimnames = list(c(1:3), c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")))
m
```

Processing:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

as.data.frame(m) %>%
  mutate(ID = rownames(m)) %>%
  gather(seqID, Value, -ID) %>%
  mutate(seqID = as.numeric(seqID))
```