# Create data frame based on three elements {rowname, colname and value}

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, data.table

Imagine the context, I have a dataframe named **Momoy** of this type :

```
Momoy = [ wow_conquests_id, lol_defeats_id, values ]
```

where inside each colnames are a finite amount of integer values.

Based on that, I'm wondering how I can create an another dataframe named **Boboy**, where *Boboy* is the transformation of Momoy in a 2D perspective, where :

```
{ wow_conquests_id } is the rownames
{ lol_defeats_id } is the column names
{ values } is the value of the intersection of the row/colnames
```

My goal is not to finish this, but more to achieve this in a powerful and robust way. I'm open for data.table tricks, setNames, ecetera ...

I'm presently capable of construct the structure of the Boboy dataframe as follows but without any values inside :

```
 Boboy <- setNames(as.data.frame( matrix( NA, nrow = length(wow_conquests_id), 
                                                 ncol = length(lol_defeats_id) ),
                             row.names = wow_conquests_id), nm = lol_defeats_id )
```

I am open to any other type of thoughts or approaches, thanks.

Comment: It sounds like `dcast(Momoy, wow_conquests_id ~ lol_defeats_id)` with data.table or other stuff you'll see in a search about "reshape long to wide"

Comment: It seems to be that I'll take a look, thank you!

Comment: If `Boboy` is a rectangular *matrix* (dims defined by lengths of `wow` and `lol`), then isn't this just `Boboy[ cbind(Momoy[[1]], Momoy[[2]]) ] <- Momoy[[3]]`? From there, it's just a simple `as.data.frame`. Am I over- or under-complicating things?

Comment: Lookup `tidyr::spread` too

Comment: Thanks buddies, I’ll check that as soon as I can. Tomorrow certainly, thanks everyone :)

Comment: `as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(values ~ ., Momoy))` too - this is essentially the reverse of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176781/r-matrix-to-rownames-colnames-values/11176964